# Percentage showing as NULL after using NULLIF() - How to show 100% and 0%?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

A helpful answer here showed me the NULLIF function to avoid the division by 0/0 error but now the percentages still show as NULL when one figure is 0. I have attached the code below and an image of the output. Is there a simple way around this?

```
SELECT 
  a.Game,
  IFNULL(SUM(a.ps_global), 0) AS ps_sales,
  IFNULL(SUM(a.xbox_global), 0) AS xbox_sales,
  SUM(a.ps_global / NULLIF((a.xbox_global + a.ps_global), 0) * 100) AS ps_pct,
  SUM(a.xbox_global / NULLIF((a.ps_global + a. xbox_global), 0) * 100) AS xbox_pct

FROM 
  aka-data-analysis-test.games.DF_A AS a

INNER JOIN
  aka-data-analysis-test.games.DF_B AS b
  ON a.Game = b.Name

GROUP BY 
  a.Game
```

Output:

[image]

Thank you all

Comment: you are dividing with 0 and as we all know from school, that infinity and only if you use the limes, so reconsider your approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

B + C will be *null* if either of them is *null*, so a way could be:

```
SUM(a.ps_global / NULLIF((IFNULL(a.xbox_global,0) + IFNULL(a.ps_global,0)), 0) * 100) AS ps_pct,
```

However, I think in that situation you probably want to do SUM(A)/SUM(B+C) rather than SUM(A/(B+C)) because SUMS of ratio are rarely meaningful.

So a clean way would be:

```
SAFE_DIVIDE(SUM(a.ps_global),SUM(IFNULL(a.xbox_global,0) + IFNULL(a.ps_global,0))) AS ps_pct
```

And if you want the division to be 0 instead of *null* you can do:

```
IFNULL(SAFE_DIVIDE(SUM(a.ps_global),SUM(IFNULL(a.xbox_global,0) + IFNULL(a.ps_global,0))),0) AS ps_pct
```

Comment: Xavier you are my favourite person ever. Thank you so much